# resolve assembly with name changed after build

Tags: c#, reference, assemblies

I am creating an add-on utility executable to another product. My executable runs on classes within the original product (I am building my tool in the same VS solution with the product project referenced). So when debugging within the project my solution works fine. When I test in the released product however my application fails with error `Cannot Load File or Assembly "product assembly name"`. The reason for this is that in the release product a post-build script runs which changes the product filename. In the released product directory if I rename the product filename back to the original, my utility will work. So as a temporary fix the next thing I tried was to create a temporary copy of the file and rename it then delete it at the end of my utility script, but the file is then locked and cannot be deleted until the AppDomain is unloaded. I have been looking for a solution for a while with no luck so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why are you renaming it in the first place, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: build it right the first time...

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing I can do about that, I did not create the original product. Ideally for me it would not be renamed. They do it to differentiate the different product types (designer vs customer)

Comment: sounds like you will have to load/shim the library manually... theres not much you can do when the assembly name changes...

Comment: @DanielA.White The post-build script changes the file name but not the assembly name within the file. But what you are saying is I would have to do an assembly load and call each class from that loaded assembly manually?

Answer (score 0):

While I could not find a way to reference my entire assembly, I did stumble across [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13747/Dynamically-load-a-class-and-execute-a-method-in-N) which made loading methods from my assembly very easy.